# Is Animation is attached to rig (skeleton) or mesh?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I would like to know: When we add an animation, it is attached to rig body (skeleton) or to mash ? And if they are different, why? I'm confused ?

Please explain, rig, animation, mash and skinning, and can we apply that skeleton animation to other mash by skinning ?

Answer (score 1):

Animation data is attached to the object that has the properties being animated.

For a rigged mesh, the mesh is dynamically deformed to follow the armature positions. You animate the movement of the armature bones and the mesh follows. So the armature contains the animation data.

If an armature already has animation data and you attach a new mesh to it, the new mesh will follow the existing animation of the armature.